# Does the US Schengen entry ban expire on April 13th 2020?

Tags: usa, eu, covid-19

On March 13th President Trump temporarily banned travelers from the EU:

> While announcing the entry restriction for European countries,
>   President Donald Trump addressed to the American people on Wednesday
>   that all the travel and import coming from 26 European Union countries
>   that are part of the Schengen Agreement will be banned as well.
>
> Within a few minutes, the White House officials clarified that the
>   30-day ban would only be applied to nationals coming from the EU, and
>   not to all goods.

Does this ban actually expire on April 13th?

Answer (score 16):

The [proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) remains in effect until the president says otherwise:

> Sec. 4.  Termination.  This proclamation shall remain in effect until
>   terminated by the President.  The Secretary of Health and Human
>   Services shall recommend that the President continue, modify, or
>   terminate this proclamation as described in section 5 of Proclamation
>   9984, as amended.

A period of thirty days was discussed when the original proclamation was made, but it doesn't appear in the actual document. In any case, I'd be very surprised if it wasn't extended.

Comment: At this point NY alone has more cases than Italy, so no point in extending it...

Comment: @JonathanReez Actually there are good reasons for both sides to extend their bans until only a very few new cases occur and active cases at least are around 5 %.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the US didn't ban domestic flights, so someone flying from NYC to Seattle is a lot more likely to be infected than someone flying from Germany.

Comment: @JonathanReez at this point, theres value in reducing the strains of SARS-CoV-2 that populations are exposed to, just incase, so keeping the separation between countries and continents has just as much value as domestic separation.

Comment: @JonathanReez This question is not about US domestic flights. In the European Union, domestic flights (travel of all kinds) are restricted for the same reasons: prevention of spreading and thus Wave 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @JonathanReez Until a vaccine or reliable antibody test are commonly available, a resumption of travel as it was until last year is unrealistic.

Comment: @JonathanReez "At this point NY alone has more cases than Italy, so no point in extending it": even if that were true, it would have no predictive value.  The Trump administration has shown that its actions are unfettered by such inconvenient restrictions as sense and logic, especially where immigration and public health are concerned.

Comment: @phoog If you've nothing valuable to add, then do not speak. The early China flights ban has spared my state, California, from the worst of the epidemic. If POTUS had banned EU travel a month earlier, NY wouldn't be in this situation. So maybe you & your fellow NY'ers should have a little humility & reflect on why you're in the situation you're in. (Edited by a mod to replace the emojies with text as they do often not show up.)

Comment: @TianxiangXiong that's exactly my point.  The China ban could have been implemented better (for example with respect to US citizens traveling from China) and travel restrictions from the EU could have been implemented earlier.  The Trump administration has done a couple of things right, but for the most part they're making a horrible mess of it.  The infection rate in New York is ample testament of that.

Comment: Please keep the comments on topic, not fighting about unrelated topics and who is responsible for whatever.